# Httpd Process High memory usage

Tags: apache, memory

Having some problems with httpd (Apache/2.2) memory usage.

Over time, memory usage in the httpd processes creep up until it's eventually at 100%. then it will restart automatically

The problem seems to be related to a specific machine (a different
machine with a similar configuration (Apache 2.2, code , OS version)
does not exhibit this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `MaxRequestsPerchild` to recycle the processes periodically.